# M1 mac magic keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard

I stupidly wiped down my M1 magic keyboard without switching it off, and now it's exclusively typing symbols... any advice for getting back to normal?

Comment: Wiped it down with what, and how damp with whatever was it?  Same character or different characters?

Comment: What characters?  Can you provide a sample?

Answer (score 0):

Your option key and/or shift is stuck or damaged

This is what I get if I hold the option key

¥ø¨® øπ†ˆø˜˚´¥ ˆß ß†¨˚ ø® ∂åµå©´∂  ∫ ˜ µ

Use air-can (get it in store) and blow it out